# Regular expression match first found value

Tags: regex, perl

I have a program-generated HTML file, and this tag is repeating:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="pt1:pt_region0:0:resId1:5:pgl3">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="pt1:pt_region0:0:resId1:4:pgl3">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="pt1:pt_region0:0:resId1:3:pgl3">
```

How do I get only the first number (5) with a regular expression and ignore other indexes?

Comment: Why not just run your regular expression once and see the result?  If you don't run it multiple times it won't match multiple times.

Comment: What is the code you're using now to process the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, and this is assuming from your question (which is not quite clear) that you want to extract the actual index value from the tag:

```
$index =~ s/resId1:(\d+):pgl3/$1/g
```

Comment: I would tend to agree with @cjac if it is XML parsing you are in fact doing. Again your question is not that clear.

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't be using regular expressions to parse html.  Take a look at [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](http://p3rl.org/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath).

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content(q{
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="pt1:pt_region0:0:resId1:5:pgl3">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="pt1:pt_region0:0:resId1:4:pgl3">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="pt1:pt_region0:0:resId1:3:pgl3">
});
my @id = $tree->findvalues('//table/@id');

my (@part) = split(/:/, $id[0]);

my $number = $part[4];

print("The number I'm looking for is [$number]\n");
```

Comment: Thank you for not using an actual regex (/:/ excluded).

Comment: Agreed... however if he is just lifting the values from the XML treated as plain text then a regular expression might be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$index=~ /resId1:(\d+):pg/;
my $value = $1;
```

so that you get your value in a scalar, whithout modifying your line